# How to list the contents of a subdirectory after finding the directory

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

This is a rather specific question, but essentially what I was wondering is if there is anyway to list the contents of a directory below the one that I search for.

My case is that I have a parent directory with a ton of subdirectories that I want to search on to see if they contain a directory of a certain string. Since it's so big I make sure to limit my depth to two to avoid unnecessary searching. The first command is something like this:

`find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "MWACluster15"`

This will typically return something on the order of 30 matches. What I'd like to do then is list the contents of one of its subdirectories called logs. I thought maybe doing something like

`find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "MWACluster15" | xargs ls logs/`

might do the trick but it just returns the immediate contents of the directory. What I want is to list the contents of `MWACluster15/logs/`

Anyone know if this is possible without having to write a bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could use something like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "MWACluster15" -execdir ls {}/logs/ \;
```

`-execdir` executes a command from the directory in which the directory you're interested in is found. The `{}` is a placeholder which is substituted with the directory name "MWACluster15".

Comment: It's just part of the `-execdir` syntax (it terminates the command to be executed for each result). Alternatively, if you want to pass all of the directories to `ls` at the same time, you can use `+` instead of `\;`